# jQuery Datatables function on each td

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to call a function on each item in my datatable with the class 'x', but it only applies to the first datatable-page...

How can I apply function on each td with class 'x' in a paginated datatable?

Comment: are you talking about https://datatables.net/ ? Please provide more details.

Comment: Correct, Kiran. Using that plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the row callback : **fnRowCallback**

```
   $(document).ready( function() {
     $('#example').dataTable( {
       "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
         // Bold the grade for all 'A' grade browsers
         if ($(nRow).is(".XClass") )
         {
           // execute you code here 
         }
       }
     } );
   } );
```

Here is an [example](http://live.datatables.net/eyexos/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest binding a click event to the Next/Prev buttons to call a function for each TD with class x found

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //bind the click to listen for Next/Prev buttons
    $('#next_button, #prev_button').on('click', function(){
        //loop through all available TDs with a class of x
        $('td.x').each(function(key, value){
            //implement function call
            $(this).someFunction();
            //or
            someFunction($(this));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this better than setting them all at once?

Comment: The $.each() technically makes this slower than setting all at once. I simply wasn't sure what function you wanted to call. Instead of looping the each you can certainly do $('td.x').addClass('cool_class'); or whatever else you desire.

Comment: My function uses Date.js to format every UTC date (text) to something more friendly. So, .each is probably the best solution here...

Comment: I will have to take your word for it because I have not used date.js before. I would certainly be interested in seeing a snippet once you get it working.